# How to store a value and increment it in a stateful widget in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm making a quiz app Currently it has two pages - a loading screen(QuizPage()) which fetches the question from an API  and a LivePage() which displays the questions fetched. To get the next question, it goes back to  the loading screen. I want to get the score of the player, but since my app goes to the loading screen every time to get the next question, the value stored in LivePage() gets reset.

````
  @override
  _QuizPageState createState() => _QuizPageState();
}

class _QuizPageState extends State<QuizPage>{

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getQuestion();
  }

  Future getQuestion() async{
  NetworkHelper net = NetworkHelper();
  var data = await net.networkHelper();
  var unescape = new HtmlUnescape();
  String question = unescape.convert(data["results"][0]["question"]);
  String answer = unescape.convert(data["results"][0]["correct_answer"]);
  String c1 = unescape.convert(data["results"][0]["incorrect_answers"][0]);
  String c2 = unescape.convert(data["results"][0]["incorrect_answers"][1]);
  String c3 = unescape.convert(data["results"][0]["incorrect_answers"][2]);
  List q = [answer,c1,c2,c3];
  q.shuffle();
  Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LivePage(answer: answer, question: question, choices: q, )));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SpinKitCircle(
          size: 100,
          color: Colors.black87,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
} 



class LivePage extends StatefulWidget{

  final List choices;
  final String question;
  final String answer;
  LivePage({this.choices, this.question, this.answer});

  @override
  _LivePageState createState() => _LivePageState();
}

class _LivePageState extends State<LivePage>{

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
          body: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(widget.question, style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 20,
              ),),
              RaisedButton(
                  onPressed: () => checkAnswer(widget.choices[0]),
                  child: Text(widget.choices[0]),
              ),
              RaisedButton(
                onPressed: () => checkAnswer(widget.choices[1]),
                child: Text(widget.choices[1]),
              ),
              RaisedButton(
                onPressed: () => checkAnswer(widget.choices[2]),
                child: Text(widget.choices[2]),
              ),
              RaisedButton(
                onPressed: () => checkAnswer(widget.choices[3]),
                child: Text(widget.choices[3]),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
} ```
````